# Comparing Strings - ASCII SPACE

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between doing this:

```
Dim strTest As String
If strTest > " " Then

End If
```

and this:

```
Dim strTest As String
If strTest <> "" Then

End If
```

I think that code sample 1 is comparing ASCII values (the ASCII code of a SPACE is 32).  I have looked through the String section on MSDN but I am unable to find an answer.

**Update**

I am also confused about what happens here:

```
 Dim strTest As String = "Test"
  If strTest > " " Then

  End If
```

Comment: I think that it is not ASCII, but (as no string comaprer can be selected with the greater than operator) whatever the current computer's culture's list order. This is why it is better to use CompareTo with a string comparer. The second query is a simple true false, whereas the first is a range inclusion/exclusion, as you suspected.

Answer (score 1):

The `>` (greater than) operator will test by alphabetical order or character code value order (depending on the `Option Compare` setting), whereas the `<>` (not equal) operator tests for equality.  As long as the two strings are different at all, then `<>` will always evaluate to `True`.  `>` will evaluate to true as long as the string on the right side of the operator comes after the first string alphabetically, or by character code value.  Therefore:

```
Option Compare Text  ' Compare strings alphabetically

...

Dim x As String = "Hello"
Dim y As String = "World"

If x <> y Then
    ' This block is executed because the strings are different
Else
    ' This block is skipped
End If

If x > y Then
    ' This block is skipped
Else
    ' This block is executed because "Hello" is less than "World" alphabetically
End If
```

In your question, however, you are comparing a null string variable (set to `Nothing`) with an empty string.  In that case, the comparison operators treat a null variable as an empty string.  Therefore, `Nothing <> ""` should evaluate to `False` because both sides of the operator are considered empty strings.  An empty or null string should always be considered the first in the sort order, so `Nothing > "Hello"` should evaluate to `False` because an empty string comes before everything else.  But, `Nothing > ""` should evaluate to `False` because they are both equal and therefore neither comes before or after the other.

To answer you final question, `"Test" > " "` will test if the letter T comes before or after a space.  If `Option Compare` is set to `Text`, it will compare them alphabetically and should return `True` (this ultimately depends on the alphabetic sorting for your locale).  If `Option Compare` is set to `Binary`, it will compare them based on their character code values.  If they are ASCII strings, a space character has a lower value than a letter, like T, so it, also, should return `True`.

Comment: thanks.  Can you modify your answer to include what happens if the String equals "" and you test using: if string > " "

Comment: I have updated the question.  Can you answer the final point?